# python: CommandError: You appear not to have the 'mysql' program installed or on your path

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am working on a Mysql database for a Django app, so I created a database named maison, configure settings.py as bellow:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'maison',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '1234',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',

}
}
```

And to verify if my database is connected to my app I run the command `python manage.py dbshell`
But it throws that error :

> CommandError: You appear not to have the 'mysql' program installed or on your path.

though I have installed all the requirement:

- Python:  3.6
- Django: 1.11
- MySQL: 5.7
- mysqlclient

Do you have any idea to fixe that error??

Comment: Did you installed `MYSQL` locally ?

Comment: No I instaled it globally.

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with the code, Django simply runs console app **mysql**. Try to call it from console without Django. Maybe it not installed, not in PATH enviroment variable or not yet in PATH enviroment variable (try to **rehash** command or console relogin if you have **rehash** command).

```
class DatabaseClient(BaseDatabaseClient):
executable_name = 'mysql'

@classmethod
def settings_to_cmd_args(cls, settings_dict):
    args = [cls.executable_name]
    db = settings_dict['OPTIONS'].get('db', settings_dict['NAME'])
    user = settings_dict['OPTIONS'].get('user', settings_dict['USER'])
    passwd = settings_dict['OPTIONS'].get('passwd', settings_dict['PASSWORD'])
    host = settings_dict['OPTIONS'].get('host', settings_dict['HOST'])
    port = settings_dict['OPTIONS'].get('port', settings_dict['PORT'])
    cert = settings_dict['OPTIONS'].get('ssl', {}).get('ca')
    defaults_file = settings_dict['OPTIONS'].get('read_default_file')
    # Seems to be no good way to set sql_mode with CLI.

    if defaults_file:
        args += ["--defaults-file=%s" % defaults_file]
    if user:
        args += ["--user=%s" % user]
    if passwd:
        args += ["--password=%s" % passwd]
    if host:
        if '/' in host:
            args += ["--socket=%s" % host]
        else:
            args += ["--host=%s" % host]
    if port:
        args += ["--port=%s" % port]
    if cert:
        args += ["--ssl-ca=%s" % cert]
    if db:
        args += [db]
    return args

def runshell(self):
    args = DatabaseClient.settings_to_cmd_args(self.connection.settings_dict)
    subprocess.check_call(args)
```

Comment: I am actually using Windows system,

Comment: It does not matter for subprocess module.

Answer (score 0):

mysql-client path may not be added in your machine.

for linux please execute the below command line:

echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile

If it is a windows system please add the mysql-client path in the environment.

Answer (score -5):

Try running `python manage.py shell`, it worked for me and I think it will work for you too!

Comment: He asked for dbshell, but not for shell